# Calculating with constants with tolerance

Tags: logarithms, standard-error

I have a formula. LogC= (LogA - 0.80 * LogB - 8.40)/0.50

However, all these constants 0.80, 8.40 and 0.50 have +/- tolerances which are not equal. Respectively, +0.13/-0.15, +4.55/-4.20, +0.12/-0.20. So I want to calculate LogC value with error depending on these tolerances. But im stuck how to calculate it. First i thought that i should take the greatest values of these constants on numerator and the smallest value on deminator for the max value and vice versa for min value. Then, max+min/2 would be my value and max-min/2 would be my error. However, in this way errors go crazy. Probably i need to use a different method to calculate errors. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $\log C$ as a function of the constants and call the latter $x,y,z\,:$
$$
\log C=f(x,y,z)=\frac{\log A-x\log B-y}{z}\,.
$$
Then use
\begin{align}
df&=\partial_x f\,dx+\partial_y f\,dy+\partial_z f\,dz
=-\frac{\log B}{z}\,dx-\frac{1}{z}\,dy-\frac{f}{z}\,dz\,.
\end{align}
Plug in $dx=0.13+0.15=0.28$ and so on. This should give a reasonable error $df\,.$

Since $f$ is not linear in $z$ we only get an approximation of its error. This can be improved by using higher order terms in a Taylor expansion.

Comment: I guess it's the one i seek for. I'll try to use it in my work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wonder that if i want to calculate plus error and minus errors separately, do i have to take dx, dy and dz all positive tolerances at once and vica versa or since z is the deminator, plus tolerance for x and y and minus tolerance for z and vice versa?

Comment: What stops you from doing it ? Same formula applies.

Comment: for instance, for positive one should they be +0.13, +4.55, +0.12 or +0.13, +4.55, -0.20?

Comment: You never told us what $\log A,\log B$ are. So we don't know if they (and $f$) are positive or negative. Apart from that: if you want the largest increase of $f$ take those signs into account and apply the "correct" changes of $x,y,z\,.$

Comment: In base 10, LogA is a number around 29-33, LogB is a number around 38-41 (there are many data of logA and logB). They are always possive and logB is always greater than logA.  Theoritically, LogC must always be between 0-5 however, there are some incorrect data so in some cases it goes negative. (That's okay). And yes i seek for the largest increase and decrease so as i understand from what you said i should use correct signs for each case, like +, +, - or -, -, + tolerance values

Comment: To be on the safe side I would calculate all eight possible values of $df$ and take the max.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: @EgeTunç . BTW we can easily get rid of the problem I mentioned in the last sentence of the answer. No need to take any derivatives. Just calculate directly $\Delta f$ as a difference between $f$ at $x,y,z$ and $x\pm \Delta x,y\pm \Delta y,z \pm \Delta z\,.$ Gives you again eight differences of which you can take the max.

Comment: I can try that but derivative way gave me what i exactly need. Btw, shouldn't the partial derivative of f respect to x has minus sign?

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a better way i found:
$$df=\sqrt{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx)^2+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy)^2+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz)^2}$$ or
$$\Delta f=\sqrt{(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \Delta x)^2+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \Delta y)^2+(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \Delta z)^2}$$

Where dx, dy and dz are errors of x, y, z, respectively.